# Socket.io as a choice to implement real time notifications system

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nestjs, backend

I want to implement a real time notification system in next js so i've chosen socket.io to acheive this goal.
Notifications are not biredirectional they are sent from server to client.
i doubt if socket.io is a good choice. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Web Sockets are a perfect solution.

Comment: The problem is the nest js documentation and the lack of ressources about websockets i'm trying to get the user data using the session in the event listener of the socket . i've done a ton of google searches but without any progress.

Comment: The best way to start without losing too much time is just to go trough the Getting Started https://socket.io/get-started/ Once you understand the syntax and workings - should be no fuss to move some codes to Nest?! There are also many tutorials all around the web and youtube...

Comment: I've used socket io before in express on a simple game project ...my problem is using session authentication inside the websocket listners on the server side .i'm trying to get the current userId using its session id .